# Button loaded through JavaScript returns a length of 0 even when continuously checking

Tags: jquery

*Edit: I just realized it is in an iframe. I think that is the issue.

We are using Brightcove player that places a play button on the video.

When I go to dev tools in chrome and console.log the length, it returns 0. If I right click the button and inspect it, then console.log the length it returns 1. If I don't right click it and inspect it though, even though it is in the DOM, it still returns 0.

I have the following code to try and detect when it is loaded. This console.logs "checking" continuously. How do I target this element that is loaded through JavaScript. Here is the code I am using:

```
$.fn.checkForPlayButton = function () {
    if ($('#vjs_video_3').length === 0) {
        var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('checking');
            $(this).checkForPlayButton();
        }, 200);        
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    };

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).checkForPlayButton();
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about `$('#vjs_video_3').length` returns `0` and `1`?

Comment: @CharlieFish Yes. If I just console log it after the page is loaded, it returns 0 even though the button is obviously there (I see it). If I right click it, inspect it, and then console log it, it returns 1.

Comment: I would probably contact Brightcove player then. Nothing totally stands out at me after looking at it for a bit that would be wrong.

Comment: It's weird, I just console.logged it a bunch of times and it returned 0, then I right clicked it once and inspected it and tried again and it returned 1. It's like it doesn't know it exists until I interact with it even though I see it.

Comment: Can you please show an actual live example of that happening? And what is it that you are trying to _achieve_ here in the first place? When people are "waiting" for stuff using timeouts or intervals, they often do so instead of actually properly using events. The Brightcove Player API offers several that you can subscribe to, have you checked whether none of those fits whatever actual purpose it is that makes you want to "wait for" the play button ...? https://docs.brightcove.com/en/player/brightcove-player/reference/api/vjs.Player.html#eventsSection